# Configuring a spring-batch without using any XML

Tags: java, spring-batch, etl

Disclaimer: I am a noob in Spring. What I am asking may be very "odd" as *I don't even know what I don't know*.

I am trying to create a batch data movement/manipulation tool (may I say a ETL tool) using Java. Someone suggested me to check out `spring-batch` which I really liked as it has many libraries for data reading/writing and processing.

But my trouble is- my data sources (flatfile or table) are not fixed. There is a fronted where user will select which flatfile or database table(s) they want to load and the program will automatically load that. This means, usual things like:

- Source / target entity structures
- source or target database URL/DSN
- Job parameters etc.

are not pre-determined in my case. They are determined in runtime. But, so far, whatever `spring-batch` examples I have seen - they have configured these information in XML. I can't do that as that will make these information static.

My Question is - If I do not want to use Spring Container (and all its XML based bean configuration) but still want to use `spring-batch` to take advantage of it's batch processing libraries, will that be possible/viable?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use the Spring Container for using spring batch and all its XML or annotation based bean configuration. However, what you are trying is achievable, you just need to find way to make it configurable by using parameters in Spring batch. You can take anyone example from internet and start working on it to make it configurable.

1. Like you can utilize file reader from Spring by simply writing custom mapper. You save the effort to create and maintain file reading logic.
2. You can have writer which can query which you create dynamically based on your table and file at run time.

Examples shows everything in xml for making simple to understand, how ever if you explore little bit almost everything can be done at runtime.

Comment: I have done some time back with xml configuration, my table and file columns were decide at run time. You start working with this idea,and then if you got stuck we will help you out here.

Comment: This is exactly my case as well - my tables and files columns are dynamic. Are you suggesting that those dynamic cases can all be configured using parameters in spring batch XML?

Comment: yes, parameters and then custom mapper etc. You need take thing case by case and find the solution. Spring batch is really flexible and good tool for this kind of job in java. It may be look little bit complicated making things configurable but later it saves lot of time and effort.